# How to avoid Instagram API error '429 too many requests'

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have an hard problem to solve:
I have a list of Instagram users and I need to extract the list of 'following' from each account.
In order to simplify the requests, (using Python) I use a module called 'igramscraper'.
I structured the script in this way:
I create two functions (one to extract followers and another one to put it into a database)
I create a for loop which iterate over the usernames and for each user in the loop I call the two functions.
I put a time.sleep time among the iteration of the user.
In the code that extracts the followers, I first need to check if the account still exists, then I need to make a requests to get if account is private or not and then If account-is_private==False I extract the relative followers.

As I said, I put a sleep of about 2 minutes among the users loop, a time.sleep between the account private request and account following request and at the end, throught a try/except, if I get a 429 error too many request, a time.sleep of about 2 hours.

The problem is that even if I wait 2 hours, Instagram allows me to do the first 100/150 requests, then refuses my requests every time  I try to do it.

Is there any way or advice to avoid the problem?? The code is the following:

```
from igramscraper.instagram import Instagram
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import time
from pymongo import MongoClient
import random

global login_username, instagram, login_password,  client,db,user_data, data, bio

def getUserFollowing(username):
    global  followings

    followings = []
    headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36',
        }

    try:
        account = instagram.get_account(username)

        if account.is_private == 1:
            return print("account privated. Skipping...")
        else:
            while True:
                count = 0
                try:
                    following = instagram.get_following(account.identifier, account.follows_count, 30, delayed=True)
                    for following_user in following['accounts']:
                        if following_user.is_verified == 1:
                                                      followings.append(following_user.username)

                return username, followings, print('following scraped successfully.')

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

except Exception as e:
    return print("account doesn't exist or some error occurred.." + str(e))


def queryUserFollowing(username, followings):
    try:
        if not followings:
            return print('not insert due to private account')
        else:
            userself = {
            "username": username,
            "following": followings,
            }
            query = user_data.insert_one(userself)
        return print('data added.')
    except Exception as e:
        return ('Something went wrong in querying.')


df = pd.read_csv('/home/rootanalytics/Scrivania/follower.csv')

instagram = Instagram()


client = MongoClient()
db = client['DataUsers']
user_data = db['user-following']
cnt = 0

def loginOne():
    usm = 'username'
    password = 'pwd'
    instagram.with_credentials(usm, password)
    log = instagram.login()

    return log

loginOne()

for user in df.iterrows():
    username = user[1][0]
    getUserFollowing(username)
    queryUserFollowing(username, followings)
```

Comment: If you try in your browser, do you get the same error?  Instagram may have blocked your whole IP address because of bot activity

Comment: It works only for the first 100/200 requests. Then if I wait for two hours I got blocked.

Comment: you have to use proxies and put a sleep after the while loop